# Image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to slideshow images.Images are loaded only when the user clicks the next button i.e there is no preloading before the slideshow begins. With every image there is a supporting description which is loaded by the same javascript from an array which is stored in the javascript file. The effect of this is such that the description on next image is shown even before the image is displayed. Please suggest me some method so that i can delay displaying the desprition until the image is loaded. Also a loading symbol could be of great help. Please let me know how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Show that image in a dynamically added iframe and add an onload listener to that iframe to show the description only when it loads.
Here's an example:

```
    <script>
    var i;
    var ifm;
    var spinner;
    function popupIframeWithImageInit(id, parent, initImageNumber) {
        ifm = document.getElementById(id); 
        i = initImageNumber;
        if(ifm === null) {
            ifm = document.createElement('iframe');
        }
        if(!spinner) {
            spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
        }
        ifm.setAttribute('src', google_logos[i]);
        ifm.setAttribute('id', id);
        ifm.setAttribute('name', id);
        ifm.setAttribute('height', document.body.clientHeight - 50);
        ifm.setAttribute('width', '840');//width is fixed because the image is assumed to be fixed size 800
        ifm.setAttribute('scrolling', 'yes');
        ifm.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
        ifm.style.display= 'none';
        ifm.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = pic_description[i];
            ifm.style.display= '';
            spinner.style.display = 'none';
        };
        document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(ifm);
        spinner.style.display = '';
    }
    function next() {
        ifm.src = google_logos[++i];
        spinner.style.display = '';
        ifm.style.display= 'none';
    }
    function prev() {
        ifm.src = google_logos[--i];
        spinner.style.display = '';
        ifm.style.display= 'none';
    }
    function dismissPopupIframeWithImage(parentId, ifmId) {
        document.getElementById(parentId).removeChild(document.getElementById(ifmId));
        spinner.style.display = 'none';
        ifm.style.display= 'none';
        return false;
    }
    //use large images to see the spinner
    google_logos = ['http://sharevm.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/googlevsmicrosoft300dpi.jpg', 
    'http://hermalditaness.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/2.jpg', 
    'http://tuescape.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/tous20les20logos20google20par20aysoon.jpg', 
    'http://isopixel.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/logos-superbowl.gif'];
    pic_description = ['http://sharevm.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/googlevsmicrosoft300dpi.jpg', 
    'http://hermalditaness.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/2.jpg', 
    'http://tuescape.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/tous20les20logos20google20par20aysoon.jpg', 
    'http://isopixel.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/logos-superbowl.gif'];
</script>
<img id="spinner" src="http://publish.gawker.com/assets/ged/img/spinner_16.gif" style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:150px; display:none;"/>
<div style="" id="panel"></div>
<div style="" id="description"></div>
<div >
    <button onclick="popupIframeWithImageInit('imagePopup', 'panel', 1);">Open</button>
    <button onclick="prev();"><-- Prev</button>
    <button onclick="next();">Next --></button>
    <button onclick="dismissPopupIframeWithImage('panel', 'imagePopup');">Close</button>
</div
```

Comment: This works but i want to add a loading sign when the image is loading. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to show some code and be more specific if you want more specific answers but in the meanwhile, I think this tutorial could help you out:

[JavaScript Timers with setTimeout and setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener for the image onload event and display your text in that event handler.  Unfortunately, as with everything else, not every browser works the same way in this respect.  If you google [image onload](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=image+onload) you will find some good suggestions.